# What is missing in my regex to solve this seemingly VERY EASY problem

Tags: regex, notepad++

Would appreciate a Regex Jedi's (or young padawan's) help with this. I'm trying to replace the digits contained within the brackets in the text below with a same, unique word: `FAIT`.

#### THE INITIAL TEXT

```
[00:13]: synchro anim titre avec voix Mlèn  
[00:30]: synchro titre avec voix Jean  
[00:54]: saut d'image  
[01:05]: ombre portée sur titre
```

#### THE DESIRED RESULT

```
[FAIT]: synchro anim titre avec voix Mlèn  
[FAIT]: synchro titre avec voix Jean  
[FAIT]: saut d'image  
[FAIT]: ombre portée sur titre
```

The limits of my regex-knowledge so far have gotten me to this:

- Find: `[\d\d:\d\d]`
- Replace: `[FAIT]`

(also see [notepad++ screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRXlg.png)).

I'd really appreciate it if one of you could send me a regex solution, from which I'll learn.

Comment: You have to escape the opening bracket `\[` or else it would mean a character class.  https://regex101.com/r/ifGWJC/1

Comment: YESSS!! Thank you fourth bird! I'll remember that the "\" allows to espace a character, i.e. treat that caracter as is.

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<=\[)\d\d:\d\d(?=\])`
- Replace with: `FAIT`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\[)         # positive look behind, make sure we have [ before (have to be escaped)]
\d\d:\d\d       # 2 digit, colon, 2 digits
(?=\])          # positive lookahead, make sure we have ] after (have to be escaped)
```

**Screen capture (before):**

[image]

**Screen capture (after):**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Toto, that's some pretty advanced Regex right there (at least imo...)

Comment: @jflachap: Not really, you'll find interesting info here: https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: @jflachap: If it works for you, feel free to mark the answer as accepted, [How to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Merci ;-)